# How can I create a CSS arrow, which scales to the size of the containing div?

Tags: css

I have a div which needs to display an arrow from one of 4 directions (top, left, right, bottom) during a merge event. The div can be any size and the arrow should scale to about 30% of the div size.

I am not sure how to make the arrow in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DzMS/) scale to the size of the `.box` div without using JavaScript to set the size of the `border-width` triangle (hover over the box to see what I mean). Maybe you guys know a better way to draw the arrow.

Comment: without scale, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3DzMS/1/

Comment: this is what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3DzMS/3/

Comment: almost, I need the arrow to expand with the div.

Comment: at least with `border` and `content` arrows it seems impossible

Comment: lol i faked the effect :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9qS5H/ also i noted that it better to exchange before/after because otherwise something wrong going if you zoom page in chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is hiding the problem in fact, but may be sometime can be usefull:
(i used `zoom` to change size of the container)

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;  
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(77, 77, 77);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgb(189, 189, 189),
    0px 0px 0px 0px black inset;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 10em;
  margin: 10px;
  zoom: 200%;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  left: 0; right: 80%; 
  height: 40px; 
  top: 45%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%; top: 45%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9qS5H/)

also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9qS5H/4/) is arrow with svg data, but this can't be used when you expect to change the aspect ratio of arrow.

as  border-width can't be percentage there is no real way to get the goal

Comment: It looks like this can't really be done with CSS alone. I ended up going with a SVG background on the `after` pseudo element.